# Problem in selecting win7 while booting and no sound

Tags: dual-boot, sound

1 - Ubuntu and win7 is loaded in my computer and ubuntu is by default. To select win7 in the upper left corner list while booting i have to use up/down arrow key which is not functioning but after booting up/down key is working alright.

2 - No sound from ubuntu but in win7 sound is coming alright.

Pls help !

Comment: So you can't boot Windows 7 but you know sound is working...

Answer (score 0):

Use the ALSA sound driver, beware sometimes Linyx & Alsa start up with the sound muted!!
Find the mute checkbox in soundsettings and unclick it, now sound should be playing normally!